# Getting response times for Neo4j queries under bolt

Tags: python-3.x, neo4j

I was looking for an answer but I could not really find it. I want to find out the response times for 10 different queries using the bolt driver. I don't want to write a lot of code for this 10 queries so my question is if its possible via Neo4j Browser or Python?

Which protocol is used by the Neo4j Browser? By using "PROFILE" I get all the information I need, but it looks like the REST Api is used for that. If you click on the Code tab there is Method=Post, URL=... etc. Is it possible to change this to the Bolt protocol? The advantage of this solution would be, that I could even compare Bolt and REST API.

An alternative would be to write a short Python script for that. The advantage would be, that I could automate this task a bit. But in the Neo4j Browser I get the response time (in the GUI and also in the resulting JSON) but if I execute the Cypher Query in Python + Bolt I just get the results. Is it possible to retrieve the meta data like response time also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, in neo4j 3.0+, the bolt driver is used. You can find this by opening the settings tab in the browser :

[image]

The python driver for neo4j 3.1+ has some statistics available for the timings : http://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/beta/session.html#neo4j.v1.summary.ResultSummary.result_available_after

For example :

```
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase, basic_auth

uri = "bolt://localhost:7687"
auth_token = basic_auth("neo4j", "password")
driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, auth=auth_token)

session = driver.session()

q = "CREATE (n:Person) RETURN n"

result = session.run(q).consume()
print(result.result_available_after)
```

Comment: Ha, that looks like that I am looking for! In my version (Neo4j 3.0.4) I have a check box "Use Bolt protocol when available". If this box is activated (it was not by default) the queries seem to take about 50 % longer than before. Could that be correct? I thought, there is no difference except the communication between client an server?

The result.result_available_after is not available in my version (3.0.4) and I am not able to update at the moment. Is there another way?

Comment: Furthermore the response time is very different and the browser lags. Strange. The response time with REST is about 500 - 800 ms and in Bolt it differs between 650 and 2600 ms. Very strange.

Comment: 3.0.4 was with an older version of Bolt and its browser support. the best way maybe is to wrap your queries in a python function and log the time it takes, nothing fancy

Comment: In general I would agree, but in python the precision of times is really bad especially on a windows machine. I tried time.time(), time.clock(), datetime but that so not reliable in any way. Mostly I get differences for two times  `time.clock()*1000` (*1000 because I want to have ms)  of 1 ms....

Comment: Is it possible that I have to access the record set in some way? If I just loop through the record set the time looks as expected (approx 500 ms), if I dont loop through the record set and just execute the query the measured time is approx 1 ms...

Comment: did you added consume() ?

Comment: No. That was the problem. Thanks a lot. Everything is fine now! :)